# HybridWebView - Handle input type file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I can't find the correct way to handle an input type file that is present in the page displayed in the HybridWebView; I need to handle it in Android and iOS; I tried a lot of things, but I can't find the rigth way.

### Context

When the application start an full page HybridWebView is displayed, when I hit an input type file, nothing happens.

As a second step, obviously, if are present `multiple` or `accept` HTML5 attributes I have to handle them correctly, eg. I have to read them from the control or something similar.

### Code

The current code is the following in `HybridWebViewRenderer` in `OnElementChanged` event:

```cs
var chromeClient = new CusWebChromeClient((uploadMsg, acceptType, capture) => {
    MainActivity.UploadMessage = uploadMsg;

    var i = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
    i.SetType("*/*");

    var chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(i, "Choose file");
    //chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, new Intent[] { captureIntent });

    ((Activity)_context).StartActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
});

webView.SetWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
```

And here the Android MainActivity.cs:

```cs
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static IValueCallback UploadMessage;
    private static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    public static Android.Net.Uri mCapturedImageURI;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == UploadMessage)
                return;
            Java.Lang.Object result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.Data;

            UploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Android.Net.Uri[] { (Android.Net.Uri)result });
            UploadMessage = null;
        }
        else
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And here the `CusWebChromeClient`:

```cs
public class CusWebChromeClient : global::Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient
{
    private Action<IValueCallback, Java.Lang.String, Java.Lang.String> callback;

    public SistemiWebChromeClient(Action<IValueCallback, Java.Lang.String, Java.Lang.String> callback)
    {
        callback = callback;
    }

    // For Android < 5.0
    [Java.Interop.Export]
    public void openFileChooser(IValueCallback uploadMsg, Java.Lang.String acceptType, Java.Lang.String capture)
    {
        callback(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
    }

    // For Android > 5.0
    public override Boolean OnShowFileChooser(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback uploadMsg, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
    {
        try
        {
            callback(uploadMsg, null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to open the file when you click it in the webview ?

Comment: I want to pick a file/files from an input type file; currenlty in the HybridWebView displaying my page if an input type file is clicked nothing happens

Comment: oould you edit the web page? If you can, maybe you can use JS interaction actively call the method in native when the file is selected and pass the path of the file

Comment: I read online (and on SO) that it must be handled like the code I have poster, but is not working, and I can't find the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have a working HybridWebView with an input type file!

In MainActivity:

```
internal static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    // Handles the response from the FileChooser
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {
        if (null == UploadMessage)
            return;
        Java.Lang.Object result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok
            ? null
            : intent.Data;
        UploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Android.Net.Uri[] { (Android.Net.Uri)result });
        UploadMessage = null;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

In HybridWebVievRender:

```
    Control.SetWebChromeClient(new CusWebChromeClient((uploadMsg, acceptType, capture) =>
    {
        MainActivity.UploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            var i = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);

            //To set all type of files
            i.SetType("*/*");

            //Here File Chooser dialog is started as Activity, and it gives result while coming back from that Activity.
            ((MainActivity)this.Context).StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
        else
        {
            var i = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
            i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);

            //To set all image file types. You can change to whatever you need
            i.SetType("*/*");

            //Here File Chooser dialog is started as Activity, and it gives result while coming back from that Activity.
            ((MainActivity)this.Context).StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    }));
```

In CusWebChromeClient:

```
public class CusWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    Action<IValueCallback, Java.Lang.String, Java.Lang.String> callback;

    public SistemiWebChromeClient(Action<IValueCallback, Java.Lang.String, Java.Lang.String> callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    //For Android 4.1+
    [Java.Interop.Export]
    public void openFileChooser(IValueCallback uploadMsg, Java.Lang.String acceptType, Java.Lang.String capture)
    {
        callback(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
    }

    // For Android 5.0+
    public override bool OnShowFileChooser(WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
    {
        //return base.OnShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
        callback(filePathCallback, null, null);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this,see if it work:

in your `MainActivity`  add this:

```
private Action<int, Result, Intent> _resultCallback;
public static MainActivity Instance;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Instance = this;
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
public void StartActivity(Intent intent, int requestCode, Action<int, Result, Intent> resultCallback)
 {
   _resultCallback = resultCallback;
   StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
 }
protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
 {
    base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (_resultCallback != null)
     {
       _resultCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       _resultCallback = null;
     }
}
```

in your `CusWebChromeClient` add this:

```
private void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) 
                {
                    if (null == mUploadMessage || data == null)
                        return;
                    mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue (WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data));
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                }
            }
        }

[Android.Runtime.Register("onShowFileChooser", "(Landroid/webkit/WebView;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;Landroid/webkit/WebChromeClient$FileChooserParams;)Z", "GetOnShowFileChooser_Landroid_webkit_WebView_Landroid_webkit_ValueCallback_Landroid_webkit_WebChromeClient_FileChooserParams_Handler")]
public override bool OnShowFileChooser (Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {

            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            i.SetType("image/*");
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(i,"File Browser");
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE, OnActivityResult);
            //return base.OnShowFileChooser (webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: `CusWebChromeClient ` is defined in your HybridWebViewRenderer,and put the code above in it

Comment: you could define a static variable for MainActivity e.g `public static MainActivity Instance;` then call `MainActivity.Instance` in your `CusWebChromeClient` ,like above i update

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201407/discussion-between-irvin-dominin-and-leo-zhu-msft).

Comment: @IrvinDominin i have modify the answer,you could check it ,the changes in  `CusWebChromeClient `  OnShowFileChooser  method